# Passar componente de ícone por Data para o componente pai

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

Olá,

Eu tenho um **data** com ícones importados utilizando a lib do ***svg-loader*** para renderizar os SVGs na página. Mas eles chegam como ***{ "functional": true }*** e não aparecem no HTML final.

Eis um exemplo do que quero abaixo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<div class="item" v-for="item in data" :key="item.label">
  <span class="icon-main">
    <slot>{{ item.icon }}</slot>
  </span>
</div>

<script>
import IconOne from '../assets/svg/icon-one.svg';
import IconTwo from '../assets/svg/icon-two.svg';

export default {
  name: 'Component',
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
        {
          label: 'Icon One',
          icon: IconOne,
        },
        {
          label: 'Icon Two',
          icon: IconTwo,
        },
      ]
    };
  },
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Ao invés de interpolar o valor da variável `item.icon`, você deve utilizar a tag component.

https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Componentes-Dinamicos

```html
<div class="item" v-for="item in data" :key="item.label">
  <span class="icon-main">
    <slot>
      <component :is="item.icon" />
    </slot>
  </span>
</div>
```